# How to find values $f(1)$ and $f(1/2)$, where $ f(x)$ is both convex and concave?

Tags: calculus, integration, functions, derivatives

first time posting here! I got stuck at a problem and figured i needed som help. The problem goes like this:

> Let f:[0,1]->ℝ be a continuous function, with f(0)=0, which is differentiable in (0,1). The derivative of f is sketched in this [figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zrO8b.png)
>
> The graph is symmetric about x = 1/2. The area bound by the x-axis and the part of f' which lies above the x-axis is 1/3. While the area bound by the x-axis and the part of f' which lies under the x-axis is 1/12.
>
> What is f(1) and f(1/2)? For which x is f convex and for which x is f concave?

Comment: What are your thoughts? What have you tried? Where are you stuck? You need to [provide context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) for your question. Otherwise it just looks like you want somebody to do your homework for you; that's not what this site is for. If you add some appropriate context, we will be happy to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that,

$$f\left(\frac12\right)=f(0)+\int_0^{1/2}f'(x)dx$$
$$=0+\int_0^{a}f'(x)dx+\int_a^{1/2}f'(x)dx$$
$$=\frac12\cdot\frac13-\frac12\cdot\frac{1}{12}=\frac18$$

where $f(a)=0$, hence $\int_0^{a}f'(x)dx$ being half of the area above the $x$-axis and $\int_a^{1/2}f'(x)dx$ half of the area below the $x$-axis. Due to symmetry, $f(1) = 2f(1/2)=\frac14$.

Comment: That made a lot of sense. Thank you!